# ag-grid & angular: autoSizeColumns() truncates cell text

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid v21 & Angular 6, with a server side row model. I want to automatically resize the column widths, but the behaviour is not quite what I expect.

As I am getting data asynchronously, I do a `gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(...)` when I get the data in **onGridReady()** (I also tried doing this in **onFirstDataRendered()**, but it had the same behaviour).

This renders the data like this, truncating the values (screenshot 1):

[image]

If I trigger the column resize manually by double clicking the vertical column separator, like in Excel, the column is resized to what I want (screenshot 2):

[image]

My question is: how can I achieve the behaviour from screenshot 2 automatically?

(Is this a timing problem, i.e. when I manually resize by double clicking, the grid has more information than upon the initial rendering and that's why the column is resized correctly?)

**EDIT**: Seems to be a timing issue. I am now resizing in onGridSizeChanged(), and sometimes (when onGridReady() takes longer (?), and onGridSizeChanged() is called after onGridReady()), it resizes correctly.

**EDIT2**: Solved, sort of. It is a specific aspect of my use case that causes the ambiguous timing, see comments below.

Comment: where you able to solve this? I have a very basic example with this and they still truncate if the header title of the column is smaller than its content.

Comment: @JohhanSantana In my case it was a problem related to my specific implementation (see my comments to the answer below). What I can recommend is to make sure that you are resizing after all the other grid data updating has finished. I'm sorry I can't be more specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event though your initial problem seems to be related to a timing issue, there's still another problem: ag grid cannot calculate the size of the column based on rows that have not been rendered yet.

From the ag grid reference:

> autoSizeColumns() looks at the rendered cells on the screen, and works
>   out the width based on what it sees. It cannot see the columns that
>   are not rendered due to column virtualisation. Thus it is not possible
>   to autosize a column that is not visible on the screen.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#auto-size-columns

Comment: Thanks! Yes, in the meantime I understand the ag-grid flow a bit better, and it's become clearer what is really going on. I have a more complex scenario, where I get the column definitions and data from the server, but some columns are actually foreign key IDs. So the grid gets the column definitions and data, to be shown immediately and not keep the user waiting, while the foreign key IDs are resolved in the background and published using an rxjs Subject when they are done. The grid subscribes to this Subject and updates the row data with the resolved foreign key values. [...]

Comment: [...] So the resizing is correct when the grid has already rendered the resolved foreign key values, and incorrect when it has not yet done so.